# sugarcrm how to get the current contact name

Tags: php, contacts, sugarcrm

Im having a problem showing the current viewed contact name in SUGARCRM

can anyone tell me how to get the current contact name, lets say i am browsing a contact in SUGARCRM called jhon i need a PHP piece of code to get this name and store it in a variable.

I already tried this:

```
global $current_user; echo $current_user->user_name;
```

but not that is what i am looking for, I am looking for something like this to be able to get the current contact name.

Comment: What is the context? Are you looking to grab this in a logic hook? In a custom view? You will need to be in a spot that can grab the bean (the data object that contains the contact data). Then you just do a $bean->name to grab that data.

Comment: its in a view, called detailview.tpl, can i achieve it in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the `full_name` property. `$current_user` is an instance of User bean

`$current_user->full_name`

If not working try to retrieve user details using bean id of current user :

```
$user = new User();     //user object
$user->retrieve($current_user->id); //retrieve user data
$full_name = $user->full_name; // If have full name property.
```

If no full name property try to concatenate last name and first name

```
$fullname = $user->first_name .' '. $user->last_name;
```

Comment: thanx, but not that what im asking for, i need to get the contact name not the user name. 
the user name is just an example of what i want to achieve with the contact or the lead.

Comment: @islamamer please update your question, if you have contact id, then you can achieve what you want using the condition above, just instantiate the Contact module, the rest will follow

Comment: thank you  EuphoriaGrogi, 
the issue is that i cant get the id of the current Contact im browsing. 
i

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a contact record, then the .tpl file needs to have the property name of what you want to show. Your question says name, so try putting this in the file where you want it:

```
"{$fields.first_name.value} {$fields.last_name.value}"
```